Что выведется на консоль и почему это вообще компилируется? [C++]
Наткнулся на такой с++ код, мне не понятны две вещи:

Почему это вообще компилируется без std::forward?
Почему вывод в обратном порядке, то есть "if"?

Вот код:
#include <iostream>

void func(float&&) {
    std::cout << "f";
}

void func(int&&) {
    std::cout << "i";
}

template <typename T>
void test(T&& v) {
    func(v);
}

int main() {
    test(1.0f);
    test(2);
}

Мои рассуждения зашли в тупик в таком порядке:

К примеру, мы передали rvalue значение "2" в функцию test, которая принимает универсальную ссылку
Тип T вывелся как int и затем на него нацепилось &&, на данном этапе имеем int&&
Мы передаем в функцию func переменную v ( func(v) ), где v уже имеет категорию значения lvalue (любое обращение к переменной по имени - это lvalue)
Ищем функцию func с подходящей сигнатурой, которая может принять lvalue и не находим
Тупик...


Сначала выведет i, а потм f. (Прав был EWD)

Ну, не совсем тупик... В пункте 4 нет функции, которая может принять int&, но зато есть функция, которая может принять значение float, которое получается при выполнении одного преобразования типов...
